# Multiple use of IF and Match in one formula

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have an issue trying to set up a formula which will include 2 ifs and 2 Match inside.

Here is an example:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(IF(MATCH(B6,'Sheet1'!$G$3:$G,0),"Taken",IF(MATCH(B6,'Sheet2'!$G$3:$G,0),"Damaged", "Available"),"Available"))`

Result always shown that Value from B6 not found in second part of the formula which is 2nd IF, I have double checked and Value from B6 is in the range of MATCH(B6,'Sheet2'!$G$3:$G,0)

Any ideas how to solve the issue?

I have tried use IF & IFS but did not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can you try with:*

```js
=ifs(ifna(xmatch(B6,Sheet1!G3:G)),"Taken",ifna(xmatch(B6,Sheet2!G3:G)),"Damaged",1, "Available")
```

Comment: Hi Rock, thank you for your reply unfortunately it did not worked. After applying the formula I got error message : G422915883!G3:G evaluates to an out-off bounds range. First time I see this message and never used xmatch before. Do you know what’s the issue can be ?. 
Once more thank you for your reply

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: Hi Rock, Apologies for confusion, while i have been preparing a test sheet i have paste your formula again and it did work. Not sure what happened yesteday while i tried. I have tried code on the original sheet and work too. Thank you very much for your help!!!. That solve my problem!!.